# Need help interpreting PCA equations and their outcomes

Tags: pca

during the discussion about PCA my course brought up an equation that I don't really understand. Here's the equation in a more general form (zCOMFORT and zPROTECT are standardized variables):

[image]

Here's the SPSS output from an example and the formula using the values from the SPSS (the formula nows uses zC1 en zC2, but I suspect that's supposed to be just C1 en C2)

[image]

[image]

Now, my course is rather vague about what exactly C1 and C2, the outcomes of the equation, stand for. Suppose zCOMFORT=2 and zPROTECT=3, resulting in C1=2.74, what exactly does that mean? Is it the value on the principal component axis?

Thanks.